# Android:current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I've got an activity which when started on my android device overlays a small circle on the map view indicating where i am.
This is done using mylocationoverlay.
I want to know if there is any way to get the location details from mylocationoverlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy .
You can obtain your current location lattitude and longitude by the following code

```
 Double lattitude = (double)(mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6()/1E6);

 Double longitude = (double)(mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes. This was what I did first. But, I had problems integrating it while integrating it into my code. So, I went for location manager and it worked. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html#getMyLocation%28%29

check the above link.. it might will help